# ReactiveCocoa merge that completes when input signal completes

Tags: objective-c, reactive-cocoa

In ReactiveCocoa, is there a mechanism similar to `merge:` that completes when any of the signals that are being merged complete?

I found a workaround that involves concatenating the input signal with a `[RACSignal return:foo]` and then adding a `take:1` after the merge, but that seems rather long-winded. Is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 4):

Not built-in to ReactiveCoca. This is probably something you should define in a helper category on `RACSignal`, so that any long-windedness is hidden behind a nice method abstraction.

Here's an (untested) example using `materialize`, which will give you a signal of signal events so you don't need to append anything onto your input signals:

```
+ (RACSignal *)sheepishMerge:(NSArray *)signals {
    RACSequence *completions = [signals.rac_sequence map:^(RACSignal *signal) {
        return [[signal materialize] filter:^(RACEvent *event) {
            return event.eventType == RACEventTypeCompleted;
        }];
    }];

    RACSignal *firstCompletion = [[RACSignal merge:completions] take:1];

    return [[RACSignal merge:signals] takeUntil:firstCompletion];
}
```